# Can an Atheist pour my wine?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, grapes-wine

*Edited -- Thank you all for the helpful comments.*

Can an avowed non-Jewish atheist pour my non-mevushal wine for me?
Can I share a bottle of wine with him/her?

Comment: What makes you think that only a worshipper of avoda Zara would mess up your wine? Perhaps it's any gentile

Comment: http://www.ishtetl.com/index.php?/topic/219-mevushal-with-atheist-jews/ http://library.yctorah.org/lindenbaum/the-status-of-a-non-believer-regarding-wine-and-other-matters-part-1-status-of-a-shabbos-violator-in-rishonim-and-poskim/

Comment: Question is unclear. Is your question focused on the definition of *Avodah zarah* or who will mess up your wine? Please edit, accordingly.

Comment: @DoubleAA - It is indeed _any_ Gentile, not just a worshipper of avodah zarah. See my question about wine made/handled by a Ben Noach: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81290/wine-made-handled-by-bnei-noach

Comment: David H, remember that even an atheist _Jew_ handling your wine renders it not kosher.

Comment: Note the difference between *yayin nesech* (wine from which an idolotrous libation was poured) and *stam yainam* which forbids any wine moved by a nonJew. Since an atheist is even more foolish than an idol worshiper (in that he does not believe in **any** god), he would not pour a libation.

Comment: @sabbahillel  thank you for the comments..It would be great if you could expand that distinction in an answer.

Comment: That would be a different question. You would need to ask specifically what is the difference between *yayin nesech* (wine poured as a libation) and *stam yainam* wine handled by a gentile.

Comment: @sabba no that's plain wrong. whether or not he is more foolish is totally irrelevant. We don't rate other religious beliefs by foolishness.

Comment: @ezra that's not so obviously true.

Comment: @rosend those are about atheist Jews, but the question was about atheist gentiles

Comment: they both discuss the reason for the prohibition which would address whether A"Z is a necessary concern

Comment: two issues: A: non jewish person, B: atheist jew. two degrees of prohibition. 1. the scriptural pb; 2. the rabbinical law.  I advise you to begin with a narrowed question. e.g. atheist jew who makes mitsvot. or sciptural law for a non j. atheist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch YD 124:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.124.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that any non-Jew, even if they do not serve Avodah Zarah, makes any non-Mevushal wine that they produce, touch (and pour) prohibited to drink, although not prohibited to benefit from:

> כל עובד כוכבים שאינו עובד עבודת כוכבים, יינו אסור בשתיה ומותר בהנאה; ומגען ביין שלנו, שוה ליינם, שאסור בשתייה.

The Taz explains that this is due to the Issur of Benoseihem, namely, an issur due to being "friendly" with a non-Jews, in that it may lead to intermarriage.

Therefore, you may not have an atheist pour you non-Mevushal wine.

The same Pesak is given in this [article](https://www.kosharot.co.il/index2.php?id=41899&lang=HEB). Many Poskim apply this logic to Muslims as well, since they do not serve Avodah Zarah, See Shu"t Yabia Omer 7:YD:12.